# After upgrade my cron script does not find the command /usr/sbin/ssmtp

Tags: debian, ssmtp

I have several raspberries running the same cron script but after updating/upgrading jessie on one of them i get

```
ssmtp:: command not found
```

I can run that command from the command-line but running the script from the command-line fails so not really a cron problem.

I am using full path: `/usr/sbin/ssmtp`

And using that command on the command line executes fine

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

And here is snip of the script code

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o pipefail

mysendmail="/usr/sbin/ssmtp"
…
$(echo -e "To: $tophil\nSubject: $(hostname) $ip2" | $mysendmail $tophil 2>&1)
```

Comment: Please add the output of `echo $PATH`

Comment: Are you sure you get two colons in the error message? If so that would suggest you're trying to run `ssmtp:` instead of `ssmtp`

Comment: I didn’t get the double colon thing either but couldn’t see the cause

Comment: removing the `$(...)` worked. Sorry for the comment but there is no place for me to select that comment as 'solved'

Comment: Phil I've created an answer from my two comments for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm rephrasing a throw-away comment here as an answer, since the asker says it solved their problem.*

Two issues jump out at me with this code. I don't think fixing them will solve the issue with missing `ssmtp`, but apparently they do.

- Remove the `$( ... )` wrapper from the last line of your script. This tells the shell to use the output from the wrapped command, and given the way you have set up the line it will attempt to execute it. (If the command generates no output then you'll get no error.)

  ```
  echo hello
  hello

  $(echo hello)
  -bash: hello: command not found
  ```

  It's usually used to interpolate command results into a string, or to assign them to a variable

  ```
  a=$(date)
  printf "Today's date is: %s\n" "$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
  ```
- Double-quote your variables every time you use them. For example,

  ```
  echo -e "To: $tophil\nSubject: $(hostname) $ip2" | "$mysendmail" "$tophil" 2>&1
  #                                                  ^           ^ ^       ^
  ```

  There are some situations where it's not strictly necessary to double-quote variables, but as you're never wrong doing so it's easiest and safest always to quote them.

Comment: in my case. the bad code created the ssmtp:: error because there was an error returned and it was run as a command so the error which was output was `ssmtp: Auth error etc` so ssmtp: ran as a command and the error became ssmtp:: command not found. hope this helps

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you very much @phil for closing the loop. (It also explains the double colon in your very first error message.)